# Factoring a polynomial in short and simple way.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, factoring, symmetric-polynomials

**Question**: I have been given a polynomial by my teacher. I have to tell him all real and complex factors of the following polynomial.

> $(l+m+n)^5-l^5-m^5-n^5$ for reals$(l,m,n)$

**What I can observe**: It is symmetric and homogeneous.

**My approach**: I know $4$ of the factors namely $5,(l+m),(m+n),(n+l)$ by using multinomial theorem and using the odd powers.

**Problem**: I am unable to find $2$ of the factors. I see only one way to do it and it is to expand the polynomial but I dont want to do it because it will be very long.
Is there any shorter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

final detail, the quadratic factor
$$ l^2 + m^2 + n^2 + mn + nl + lm  $$
is irreducible over the reals and complexes. If you write out, using variables $x,y,z$ and complex coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f$ the form
$$ (ax+by+cz)(dx+ey+fz)   $$
then carefully construct the Hessian matrix $H$ of second partial derivatives with respect to $x,y,z$ in order, the determinant come out to be zero. 
For that matter, ignoring the determinant, all we need to do is set the triple $(x,y,z)$ to the traditional cross product $(a,b,c) \times (d,e,f)$ to get a vector that is sent to the origin by the Hessian matrix, considered as a linear transformation. That is $H$ is singular. Oh, if $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$ are actually parallel, then the rank of $H$ reduces to one.

Your Hessian comes out as
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In comparison, the Hessian of
$$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz - zx - xy   $$
comes out
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
so this time the form can be factored; first step is
$$  \frac{1}{4} (2x-y-z)^2 +  \frac{3}{4} (y-z)^2  \; \; . $$ The actual factoring becomes
$$  \left( \frac{1}{2} (2x-y-z) + \frac{i \sqrt 3}{2} (y-z) \right)  \left( \frac{1}{2} (2x-y-z) - \frac{i \sqrt 3}{2} (y-z) \right)  $$
which can be written without fractions if we introduce the cube root of $1$ given by $\omega = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt 3}{2}$
It becomes
$$ (x + y \omega + z \omega^2)(x + y \omega^2 + z \omega ) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz - zx - xy $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
(l + m + n)^5 - l^5 - m^5 - n^5 = 5(l+m)(l+n)(m+n)((l+m+n)^2-(lm+ln+mn))
$$

Comment: And how did you get your last factor?

Comment: Sorry. A typo. Now it is corrected.

Comment: A little algebra involved. You can do it by polynomial comparison.

Comment: Your last factor.

Comment: May you define it in short?

Comment: $5(l+m)\cdots (c_1a^2+c_2 n^2+c_3 n^2+c_4 l n+c_5 l m+c_6 nm) = (l + m + n)^5 - l^5 - m^5 - n^5$

Comment: Oh, and now you put values in l,m,n to get $c_1...c_6$. Also I can see $c_1=c_2=c_3$

Answer (score 1):

Given the known factors, the remaining factor must be symmetric, and homogeneous of degree $2$, hence must have the form 
$$a(l^2+m^2+n^2)+b(lm+mn+nl)$$ 
for some constants $a,b$.

To find $a,b$, just choose some values for $l,m,n$, and substitute them into the equation
$$(l+m+n)^5-l^5-m^5-n^5=5(l+m)(m+n)(n+l)\bigl(a(l^2+m^2+n^2)+b(lm+mn+nl)\bigr)$$
Using $(l,m,n)=(0,1,1)$ we get
$$30=(10)(2a+b)$$
hence $2a+b=3$.

Using $(l,m,n)=(0,1,2)$ we get
$$210=(30)(5a+2b)$$
hence $5a+2b=7$.

Solving the system
\begin{align*}
2a+b&=3\\[4pt]
5a+2b&=7\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
yields $a=b=1$, hence the remaining factor is
$$l^2+m^2+n^2+lm+mn+nl$$
To see that the above polynomial can't be factored further, substitute $l=1$.

Regarding the resulting polynomial
$$m^2+mn+n^2+m+n+1$$
as a quadratic polynomial in $m$, the discriminant is
$$-3n^2-2n-3$$
which has two distinct roots, so is not the square of a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[n]$.

It follows that $l^2+m^2+n^2+lm+mn+nl$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[m,n,l]$, hence we get the complete factorization
$$(l+m+n)^5-l^5-m^5-n^5=5(l+m)(m+n)(n+l)(l^2+m^2+n^2+lm+mn+nl)$$

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple more vectors with $l^5+m^5+n^5=0=l+m+n$ other than
$(1,-1,0)$ and their multiples and permutations. These involve complex numbers (roots of unity) though....

Comment: Yeah I need that. Factors in terms of $\omega$ if any

Comment: That's right! Of course they combine to form a quadratic factor over the reals. @LoveInvariants